Surface curl of a gradient
Just tryin to check my math here. Let's say we have a smooth and closed surface $S$ and we want to calculate the "surface curl" of a continuous and differentiable vector $\mathbf{A} = \nabla \phi$ on said surface $S$. Let's split the curl operator as follows:
$\nabla = \nabla_S + \nabla_\perp$, where $\nabla_S$ is the surface gradient $\nabla_S = \nabla - \mathbf{n}(\mathbf{n} \cdot \nabla)$ and $\nabla_\perp = \mathbf{n}(\mathbf{n} \cdot \nabla)$ and $\mathbf{n}$ is the vector normal to the surface $S$. Thus, we can say the following:
$\nabla \times \mathbf{A} = (\nabla_S + \nabla_\perp) \times \mathbf{A} = 0$.
I am thinking that the terms $\nabla_S \times \mathbf{A}$ and $ \nabla_\perp \times \mathbf{A}$ are merely components of $\nabla \times \mathbf{A}$. We know that the components of the vector $\nabla \times \mathbf{A}$ must be zero at all points on the surface given that $\mathbf{A} = \nabla \phi$.
Is this correct?
